# F# Suave warbler function

Tags: f#, suave

I've started learning F# and `Suave` and I'm reading the book *F# Applied*.

One thing I'm struggling with is the `warbler` function. I know its something to do with deferring execution but I don't really understand why and when its needed.

Apparently we could also use the `request` function as an alternative to `warbler`.

Can anyone provide any more detail on why and when these functions are used.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These three functions are related in the sense that `request` and `context` are specialized versions of `warbler`. They all do the same thing - they inspect (some aspect of) their argument and give you back a function to apply to that argument.

Remember that the basic "building block" of Suave, `WebPart`, is a function `HttpContext -> Async<HttpContext option>` rather than some concrete object. What this effectively means is that those three functions allow you to inspect this `HttpContext` and based on that compose a `WebPart` to use.

At its core, what `warbler` does is very simple:

```
let warbler f a = f a a  
// ('t -> 't -> 'u) -> 't -> 'u
```

You give it a function `f` and argument `a`. Function `f` looks at `a` and gives you back a new function `'t -> 'u` which is then applied to `a`.

The thing about `warbler` is that it's entirely generic - you can use it anywhere you'd use `context` or `request` as long as the types align, but it doesn't know anything about the domain Suave is interested in.

That's why there are the specialized versions of it that "speak the domain language":

```
let request apply (a : HttpContext) = apply a.request a
// (HttpRequest -> HttpContext -> 'a) -> HttpContext -> 'a 
let context apply (a : HttpContext) = apply a a
// (HttpContext -> HttpContext -> 'a) -> HttpContext -> 'a
```

Notice that they have the same "shape" as warbler - the only difference being that the `HttpContext` type is "hardcoded" - making it more convenient to use.

Comment: Thanks scrwtp.  Good answer.

Comment: Simple correction suggestion: `type WebPart = HttpContext -> Async<HttpContext option>`

Answer (score 32):

The other answer already explained the `warbler` function and its relation to `context` and `request` functions. I'd like to show when do you want to use these.

When you start a Suave server, you need to provide it with the request processing pipeline of `WebParts` - routing, HTTP methods and the response-generating functions. This means that by the time you start the web server all the parameters provided to the partially applied `WebPart` functions have already been evaluated.

Imagine a minimalistic web app that prints the current server time:

```
let app = GET >=> path "/" >=> OK (string DateTime.Now)
```

If you start a web server using this `app` pipeline, you'll always see the same timestamp generated when the `app` value was created, no matter when you make the web requests retrieving it.

The `warbler` function and its specialized versions `context` and `request` not only defer the execution, but also enable the web server to call the provided function every time it needs its result.

In the example scenario this `app` will provide expected results:

```
let app = GET >=> path "/" >=> warbler (fun ctx -> OK (string DateTime.Now))
```

---

@adzdavies' comment shows an alternative approach where you don't necessarily need `warbler`. In the example you can also defer the parameter evaluation if you use anonymous function syntax instead of partially applying `OK`.

```
let app = GET >=> path "/" >=> (fun ctx -> OK (string DateTime.Now) ctx)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yours and scrwtp's answer in combination are very useful. Thanks again. I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: Note that 'all the WebPart functions have already executed' isn't strictly true. In this case, just the argument to "OK" has. It doesn't really execute until a request comes in.

It is possible to replace `warbler` with a lambda, but this requires you to pass along the context: `(fun ctx -> OK (string DateTime.Now) ctx)` which is, as shown, directly derivable from it's definition (f a -> f a a)

Comment: Thanks... I was struggling to understand how suave was working, and your answer, the source code, and trying out that lambda helped make it click.

Answer (score 3):

I found the prior explanation confusing (to me). This is my attempt at clarity...

`warbler` resolves a problem with optimized impure eager evaluated functional languages in which partially applied arguments are evaluated early and cached. This caching presents a problem when those applied arguments are dependent on side effects and it becomes desirable to have fresh values with each invocation. For example, the following query for the `string` representation of the current system's time will occur and be cached at the definition of `g: string -> string`. As such, it will return the same value for each subsequent call to `g`:

```
let g = sprintf "%s %s" (string DateTime.Now)

g "a"  //"12/09/2020 18:33:32 a"
g "b"  //"12/09/2020 18:33:32 b"
```

However, the `warbler` concept is unnecessary to resolve this reevaluation issue. It is enough to simply wrap the subject function inside an anonymous function that then fully applies the subject function each time, as follows:

```
let f = (fun x -> sprintf "%s %s" (string DateTime.Now) x)

f "c"    //"12/09/2020 18:53:32 c"
f "d"    //"12/09/2020 18:53:34 d"
```

What `warbler` is doing instead is using the above anonymous function as a function factory that produces the subject function when invoked. Then invoking that subject function with its second argument. It is incidental that `warbler` uses its second argument to invoke the factory function but it does present a point of misdirection. Conceivably, passing the argument to the factory can allow the factory to configure the subject function function or select alternative type compatible functions to return to the `warbler`. Still, that is not what the `warbler` is intended for.

```
let warbler f x = (f x) x
```

It should be noted that for reevaluation to work, `f`, must be an anonymous function at the point of call. Consequently, there seems to be no longer any utility for the `warbler` concept and the cool name should probably be deprecated and allowed to resurface for some other useful concept.

Incidentally, my encounter with `warbler` is with [`Giraffe`](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/master/src/Giraffe/Core.fs).